# Grid columns are overlapping

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm a beginner practicing with grids and responsive design. I made 600px my breakpoint but when I resized the screen, the columns in my .main div just overlapped, and the footer with the social media icons won't go to the center. Here it is on codepen: https://codepen.io/charity-temple/pen/gOPvJbz

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>LOGO</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="main_imageholder">
      <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/du07lnlg2/image/upload/v1594091023/Messaging_fun-amico_1_mg8xyo.png" alt="sitting-girl">
    </div>
    <div class="textholder">
      <h1>Lead with the possibility to surprise and delight</h1>
      <p>Take stakeholder management so that as an end result, we improve overall outcomes. Repurpose cloud computing and finally make users into advocates.</p>
      <button href="#">Register</button>
    </div>
  </main>
  <div class="social">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: #34495e;
}

.container{
  border: solid white;
  width:auto;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  display: grid;
}

header{
  border: solid red;
  width:90%;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}

header > h1{
  font-weight: 900px;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

main {
  border:solid blue;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  margin:auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap:10px;
 
}

.main_imageholder{
  border:solid yellow;
  padding: 40px;
}

.main_imageholder > img{
  width: 100%;
}

.textholder{
  border: solid pink;
  padding: 30px;
}

h1{
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 32px;
}

p{
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

button{
  margin-top:20px;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: auto;
  color: #34495e;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

button:hover{
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.social{
  border: solid orange;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0px auto auto auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.social ul{
  display:flex;
}

.social > ul > li{
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px white solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 1vw;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;

}

.social > ul > li > a{
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .main_imageholder{grid-area: main_imageholder;}
  .textholder{grid-area: textholder;}
  .main{
    grid-template-areas:
      'main_imageholder main_imageholder'
      'textholder textholder'
  }
  
  .social{
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify a type selector in the first bit (node type 'main') and in the media query you specify a class type selector (node with class of 'main'). It's just a typo. Remove the period before 'main' in the media query css.

Ex:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .main_imageholder{grid-area: main_imageholder;}
  .textholder{grid-area: textholder;}
  main{
    grid-template-areas:
      'main_imageholder main_imageholder'
      'textholder textholder'
  }
  
  .social{
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you James! :D